# Using Python to run a .exe file and provide a string as an input for the program

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I am trying to run a .exe file from a Python script, the .exe file opens a command window and requires the name of a file as an input. So I am wondering how to run this .exe file and send a string, with the input file's name, to the program.

Currently, I have this:

```
#bolsig is the path to the .exe file 

p = Popen(bolsig, stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(input=b'he_test.dat')
```

The output is this:

```
BOLSIG+ script file?
forrtl: The pipe has been ended.
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit -4, file CONIN$
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source             
bolsigminus.exe    00FD8A8A  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
bolsigminus.exe    00FC09D4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
bolsigminus.exe    012A1272  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
bolsigminus.exe    01033CD5  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       74128484  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          7730302C  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          77302FFA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

But the output should be:

```
BOLSIG+ script file?
he_test.dat
```